# How to run multiple spiders in the same process in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm beginner in Python & Scrapy. I've just create a Scrapy project with multiple spiders, when running "scrapy crawl .." it runs only the first spider.

How can I run all spiders in the same process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to run multiple instances of the same spider or a group of different spiders?

Comment: I have many spiders on my project's folder "spiders". & I want to run all of them in one shot, instead of running "scrapy crawl" for each one. Also I would like to know if there is a way to automate this task, run the crawl every hour for example.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You will have a name for every spider in the file that says `name="youspidername"`. and when you call it using `scrapy crawl yourspidername`, it will crawl only that spider. you will have to again give a command to run the other spider using `scrapy crawl youotherspidername`.

The other way is to just mention all the spiders in the same command like `scrapy crawl yourspidername,yourotherspidername,etc..` (this method is not supported for the newer versions of scrapy)

Comment: Hi @Reddy thanks for replying. 
I've tried your first method and it's working, but actually I need to run all the spiders with one command.
Probably I need to code a new file.py that run every spiders or something like that, but I don't know exactly how!
You're right the other method doesn't work.

Comment: its simple . Just add the new classes to your items.py file and then import them to create(define) a new parser in your spider.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone, even the docs, suggest using the internal API to author a "run script" which controls the start and stop of multiple spiders. However, this comes with a lot of caveats unless you get it absolutely correct (feedexports not working, the twisted reactor either not stopping or stopping too soon etc).

In my opinion, we have a known working and supported `scrapy crawl x` command and therefore a much easier way to handle this is to use GNU Parallel to parellize.

After install, to run (from the shell) one scrapy spider per core and assuming you wish to run all the ones in your project:

```
scrapy list | parallel --line-buffer scrapy crawl
```

If you only have one core, you can play around with the `--jobs` argument to GNU Parallel. For example, the following will run 2 scrapy jobs per core:

```
scrapy list | parallel --jobs 200% --line-buffer scrapy crawl
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Scrapy runs a single spider per process when you run
> scrapy crawl. However, Scrapy supports running multiple spiders per
> process using the internal API.

For more information check it out here:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```